# How to block the specific websites using proxy server?

Tags: 12.04, proxy

I need to block the social networking sites like facebook, twitter, etc within my office network. I tried some proxy server and enabled settings in browser like giving IP and port number. It works but any one can disable the settings easily in the browser, and have easy access.

How do I setup a proxy server to prevent non-administrative users to access these sites?